# How rewrite foreach from Stream API to another function for calculating sum of fractions?

Tags: java, math, java-stream, fractions

I have a list of fractional numbers, I need to check that the sum of these numbers is less or equals than 1.0. How can I do this with `reduce` function from `streams api`?

Now my solution is such. But maybe is there a more beautiful way to write it?

```java
private boolean isValidSumFractions(List<Fraction> fractions) {
    org.apache.commons.lang3.math.Fraction sum = org.apache.commons.lang3.math.Fraction.ZERO;
    fractions.forEach(it -> 
            sum.add(org.apache.commons.lang3.math.Fraction.getFraction(it.getNumerator(), it.getDivider()))
    );
    return sum.compareTo(org.apache.commons.lang3.math.Fraction.ONE) <= 0;
}
```

my custom class `Fraction`:

```
@Data
public class Fraction {
    private final short numerator;
    private final short divider;
}
```

Comment: `return fractions.stream().map(it -> Fraction.getFraction(it.getNumerator(), it.getDivider())).reduce(Fraction.ZERO, Fraction::add).compareTo(Fraction.ONE) <= 0;`

Comment: Why do you have your own `Fraction` class as well as the Apache one?  Can't you just use the Apache one throughout?

Comment: @dawood-ibn-kareem I had to create my own class in order to use it as a model for rest. It contains additional validation logic.

Comment: OK fair enough.  I'd just break it into two parts.  Have a filter that converts from your Fraction into the Apache Fraction, and put that in front of something that sums the Apache Fractions.

Comment: @shmosel Perhaps you'd like to post that in the form of an answer, so that people can vote on it.  If you ping me, I will provide an upvote.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Feel free to turn it into an answer.

Comment: OK, I might do that later (CW of course).

Answer (score 0):

As written in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72639291/how-rewrite-foreach-from-stream-api-to-another-function-for-calculating-sum-of-f#comment128312120_72639291) by user @shmosel and permitted by him (in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72639291/how-rewrite-foreach-from-stream-api-to-another-function-for-calculating-sum-of-f#comment128313574_72639291)) to post as an answer, here is a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Note that the below code uses [records](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/records.html) which was first added, as a preview feature, in Java 14. Also note that I changed the name to `Frakshun` so as to avoid the name clash with class `org.apache.commons.lang3.math.Fraction`.

```java
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.math.Fraction;

public record Frakshun(short numerator, short divider) {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frakshun f1 = new Frakshun((short) 1, (short) 3);
        Frakshun f2 = new Frakshun((short) 5, (short) 9);
        Frakshun f3 = new Frakshun((short) 1, (short) 9);
        List<Frakshun> fractions = List.of(f1, f2, f3);
        boolean ok = fractions.stream()
                              .map(f -> Fraction.getFraction(f.numerator(), f.divider()))
                              .reduce(Fraction.ZERO, Fraction::add)
                              .compareTo(Fraction.ONE) <= 0;
        System.out.println(ok);
    }
}
```

Running the above code prints **true** since the sum of the three fractions, in the `List`, is 1 (one), i.e. ⅓ + <sup>5</sup>⁄<sub>9</sub> + ⅑ = 1

### Edit

As requested in OP [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72639291/how-rewrite-foreach-from-stream-api-to-another-function-for-calculating-sum-of-f/72641006#comment128315275_72641006) to my answer, below code uses [short-circuiting operation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) to possibly not process all stream elements. Note that method [takeWhile](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)) was added in Java 9.

```java
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.math.Fraction;

public record Frakshun(short numerator, short divider) {
    private static boolean isValidSumFractions(List<Frakshun> fractions) {
        Fraction[] sum = new Fraction[]{Fraction.ZERO};
        return fractions.stream()
                        .map(f -> Fraction.getFraction(f.numerator(), f.divider()))
                        .takeWhile(f -> (sum[0] = sum[0].add(f)).compareTo(Fraction.ONE) <= 0)
                        .allMatch(f -> sum[0].compareTo(Fraction.ONE) <= 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frakshun f1 = new Frakshun((short) 2, (short) 3);
        Frakshun f2 = new Frakshun((short) 5, (short) 9);
        Frakshun f3 = new Frakshun((short) 4, (short) 9);
        List<Frakshun> fractions = List.of(f1, f2, f3);
        System.out.println(isValidSumFractions(fractions));
    }
}
```

Above code will print **true** even though sum of all fractions in `List` is greater than 1 (one). Note that the code will print **false** only when the first faction in the `List` is greater than 1.

Comment: can you add a stop condition to the reducer? e.g. when sum > 1 than stop, otherwise on a large stream we have a lot of unnecessary additions or never ending additions for an endless loop :-D

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but the second version (with `takeWhile()`) would not work as expected because `Fraction` is immutable. `sum` will always remain to be `0`. And according to the documentation, *predicate* passed to `takeWhile()` should be **stateless**, i.e. this approach in essence is wrong even if you would fix the *predicate* because* it should not accumulate the value outside the stream.

Comment: The only correct way to address this problem was introduces by *@shmosel* - it's the case of reduction operation that should be performed on **immutable** objects, and `reduce()` was designed to work with immutable results of reduction, that is the most suitable option here. And there's no **clean** way to make `reduce()` to be **short-circuit**.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko _Please correct me if I'm wrong_ You are not wrong. Thank you for pointing that out. Even though the code passed all my tests, I realize that those tests did not expose the problem that you pointed out. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Although, the second snippet does what OP was asking for, it's still worth to add a brief mention (you can use this reference to the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness)) that such approach  is discouraged by the documentation so any reader (not only OP) would be warned that it's not a good practice. With that, I'll remove my comments as not reflecting the answer's state.